# I can not send the text to firebase when Button is click with redux

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, redux, react-redux

if i write this  `onPress={() => this.submit()}` instead  `onPress={() => this.onSendBtnPressed()}` i can get the text value but if i just write  `onPress={() => this.onSendBtnPressed()}` this i can't see the text on the message list

here is my chatui

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {KeyboardAvoidingView, Image, TouchableOpacity, ReactNative, 
StyleSheet }  from 'react-native';
import {Footer, FooterTab} from "native-base";
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll- 
view';
import { View, Title, Screen, ScrollView, TextInput,Text } from 
'@shoutem/ui';
import Messages from '../containers/Messages';
import Input from '../containers/Input';
import { sendMessage } from '../actions';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
chatHeight: state.chatroom.meta.height,
user: state.user,
});

class ChatUI extends Component {
 constructor()
 {
     super();
     this.state = {
        text: '',
        scrollViewHeight: 0,
        inputHeight: 0
    }
 }
 updateValue(text) {
     console.warn(text)

 }      

componentDidMount() {
    this.scrollToBottom(false);
}

componentDidUpdate() {
    this.scrollToBottom();
}

onChangeText(text) { 
    this.setState({text: text})
};

onSendBtnPressed (text) {
    return sendMessage(text, this.props.user)
    this.textInput.clear();
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    }

onScrollViewLayout = (event) => {
    const layout = event.nativeEvent.layout;

    this.setState({
        scrollViewHeight: layout.height
    });
}

onInputLayout = (event) => {
    const layout = event.nativeEvent.layout;

    this.setState({
        inputHeight: layout.height
    });
}

scrollToBottom(animate = false) {
    const { scrollViewHeight, inputHeight } = this.state,
          { chatHeight } = this.props;

    const scrollTo = chatHeight - scrollViewHeight + inputHeight;

 if (scrollTo > 0) {
   this.refs.scroll.scrollToEnd();

}
}
_scrollToInput(reactRef) {
    this.refs.scroll.scrollToFocusedInput(ReactNative.findNodeHandle(reactRef));
}
submit() {
    let collection = {}
    collection.text = this.state.text,
    console.warn(collection);
}

render() {
    return (
   <Screen >   
            <Title style={{paddingTop: 25, paddingLeft: 10, borderBottomWidth: 0.5, backgroundColor: 'white', paddingBottom: 10}}>
            <Image style={{width:80, height: 80}} source={require('../img/11.png')} />
            <Text>                    GENERAL CHAT</Text>
            </Title>
            <KeyboardAwareScrollView ref="scroll"
                                     onLayout={this.onScrollViewLayout}>
                <Messages />
    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
          <Footer style={{width:360,
                    height:30,
                    backgroundColor:'#fff',
                    borderRadius:20,
                    borderWidth: 0.5,
                    marginBottom: 3,
                    borderColor: 'gray',    
         }}>              
 <TextInput           
                onSubmitEditing = {this.onSubmitEditing}
                multiline
                   onLayout={this.onInputLayout}
                   submitAction={this.onSendBtnPressed}
                   ref="input"
                   placeholder="Say something ..." 
                   onChangeText={(text) => this.onChangeText(text, 'text')}
                   style={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                   borderBottomWidth: 1.5, borderColor: '#f8f8f8', fontSize: 16, color: 'gray', paddingBottom:20}}
                   ref={input => { this.textInput = input; } }/>   
          </Footer>
          <TouchableOpacity
                           onPress={() => this.onSendBtnPressed()}
                           style={{marginLeft:280, backgroundColor:'gray', width: 70, height: 30}}
                           title= "send"
           >  
           </TouchableOpacity>

 </Screen>       
    )
}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {sendMessage})(ChatUI);
```

and here is my actions

```
import firebase from '../firebase';
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import FCM, { FCMEvent, NotificationType, WillPresentNotificationResult, 
RemoteNotificationResult } from 'react-native-fcm';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

export const addMessage = (msg) => ({
type: 'ADD_MESSAGE',
 ...msg
});

export const sendMessage = (text, user) => {
return function (dispatch) {
    let msg = {
            text: text,
            time: Date.now(),
            author: {
                name: user.name,
                avatar: user.avatar
            }
        };

    const newMsgRef = firebase.database()
                              .ref('messages')
                              .push();
    msg.id = newMsgRef.key;
    newMsgRef.set(msg);

    dispatch(addMessage(msg));
};
};


export const startFetchingMessages = () => ({
type: 'START_FETCHING_MESSAGES'
});

export const receivedMessages = () => ({
type: 'RECEIVED_MESSAGES',
receivedAt: Date.now()
});

export const fetchMessages = () => {
return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(startFetchingMessages());

    firebase.database()
            .ref('messages')
            .orderByKey()
            .limitToLast(20)
            .on('value', (snapshot) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    const messages = snapshot.val() || [];

                    dispatch(receiveMessages(messages))
                }, 0);
            });
}
}

export const receiveMessages = (messages) => {
return function (dispatch) {
    Object.values(messages).forEach(msg => dispatch(addMessage(msg)));

    dispatch(receivedMessages());
}
}

export const updateMessagesHeight = (event) => {
const layout = event.nativeEvent.layout;

return {
    type: 'UPDATE_MESSAGES_HEIGHT',
    height: layout.height
}
}

export const setUserName = (name) => {
return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        type: 'SET_USER_NAME',
        payload: name

    });
};
};


export const setUserAvatar = (avatar) => ({
type: 'SET_USER_AVATAR',
avatar: avatar && avatar.length > 0 ? avatar : 'avatar.jpg'

});

export const login = () => {
return function (dispatch, getState) {
    dispatch(startAuthorizing());


    firebase.auth()
            .signInAnonymously()
            .then(() => {
               const { name, avatar } = getState().user;

                firebase.database()
                        .ref(`users/`)
                        .push({
                            name,
                            avatar
                        });

                        dispatch(userAuthorized());
                        dispatch(fetchMessages());


            });
}
}

export const checkUserExists = () => {
return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(startAuthorizing());

    firebase.auth()
            .signInAnonymously()
            .then(() => firebase.database()
                                .ref(`users/${DeviceInfo.getUniqueID()}`)
                                .once('value', (snapshot) => {
                                    const val = snapshot.val();

                                    if (val === null) {
                                        dispatch(userNoExist());
                                    }else{
                                        dispatch(setUserName(val.name));
                                        dispatch(setUserAvatar(val.avatar));
                                        startChatting(dispatch);
                                    }
                                }))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
}

const startChatting = function (dispatch) {
dispatch(userAuthorized());
dispatch(fetchMessages());

FCM.requestPermissions();
FCM.getFCMToken()
   .then(token => {
       console.log(token)
   });
FCM.subscribeToTopic('secret-chatroom');

FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, async (notif) => {
    console.log(notif);

    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        switch (notif._notificationType) {
            case NotificationType.Remote:
                notif.finish(RemoteNotificationResult.NewData); //other 
types available: RemoteNotificationResult.NewData, 
RemoteNotificationResult.ResultFailed
                break;
            case NotificationType.NotificationResponse:
                notif.finish();
                break;
            case NotificationType.WillPresent:
                notif.finish(WillPresentNotificationResult.All); //other 
types available: WillPresentNotificationResult.None
                break;
          }
        }
});

FCM.on(FCMEvent.RefreshToken, token => {
    console.log(token);
});
}

export const startAuthorizing = () => ({
type: 'USER_START_AUTHORIZING'
});

export const userAuthorized = () => ({
type: 'USER_AUTHORIZED'
});

export const userNoExist = () => ({
type: 'USER_NO_EXIST'
});
```

and MessageList

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    ListView, Text, Row, Image,
    View, Subtitle, Caption, Heading
} from '@shoutem/ui';
import moment from 'moment';

const Message = ({ msg }) => (
    <Row>
        <Image styleName="small-avatar top"
            source={{ uri: msg.author.avatar }} />
        <View styleName="vertical">
            <View styleName="horizontal space-between">
                <Subtitle>{msg.author.name}</Subtitle>
                <Caption>{moment(msg.time).from(Date.now())}</Caption>
            </View>
            <Text styleName="multiline">{msg.text}</Text>
        </View>
    </Row>
);

const MessageList = ({ messages, onLayout }) => (
    <ListView data={messages}
            autoHideHeader={true}
            renderRow={msg => <Message msg={msg} />}
            onLayout={onLayout}
            />
);

export default MessageList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are not passing a `text` variable into your `onSendButtonPressed` function. It looks like you should be calling it using the following syntax:

   `onPress={() => this.onSendBtnPressed(someText)}`
2. Your `onSendBtnPressed()` function has the return statement on the first line, so the code will not be fired underneath the return statement (not related to your question, but hope to fix any other headaches...)

Comment: onPress={() => this.onSendBtnPressed(text, 'text')} Like this? I tried, but when I click on the button, nothing happens.

Comment: i fix this by changing the function and with the above onSendBtnPressed (text) {
        
        this.props.sendMessage(this.state.text, this.props.user);
        
        
        }